# Cypress: Intercept an image/png GET request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress

I am trying to intercept a png image request and check part of its request. For instance, the GET request `data:image/png;base64,ASDFASDGHTRADBT#$%GDFWSDFDAAAAAAAAA`, I wan't to check that there are more than 5 A's. So far I have tried this but it can't intercept the request. Can anyone help with this?

```
cy.intercept('data:image/png').as('img')

cy.wait('@img').its('request.url').should('contain','AAAAA')
```

Comment: Does this help `cy.intercept('**/data:image/png*')`

Comment: still failing to intercept any of the requests